# Problem in understanding Chain rule for partial derivatives

Tags: partial-derivative

I'm having trouble understanding the chain rule for partial derivatives.
If I'm given that $\omega=f(x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are functions of both $t$ and $r$, then by chain rule I can write that:
$$\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$$

But if I'm asked to find out what $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is equal to then can I write that it's equal to $\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x}?$ If I'm wrong then what is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ equal to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\omega$ is defined as $f$, then $\partial f/\partial x = \partial \omega/\partial x$. In general:
$$
\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x}  = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\quad 
\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial y}  = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t},\quad 
\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial r}  = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}.
$$

Comment: If I consider an example, $w=sin(xy)$, then  $\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x}=ycos(xy)$. But $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=cosxy$. Which means they're not equal?

Comment: Your steps are not correct, because $f(x,y) = \sin xy$, so $\partial f/\partial x = y\cos xy$.

Comment: But $f$ corresponds to $sin$ only isn't it? Not the variables passed to the function

Comment: No, $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}: (x,y) \mapsto \sin xy$.